# Generating UUIDs with 6 character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, unique, uuid

For ruby, Gem [UUID](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/uuid/2.3.8) generate 36-character UUIDs. 
I want to generate only 6-character based on input number(user_id).
Is it possible if the total number of users does not exceed 9_999_999?

Comment: You can generate 6 char random strings, but they won't be universally unique (can't be)

Comment: If you want unique use a UUID, don't try to roll your own.  For user friendly display do what GitHub does and only show the first 8 characters.

Comment: Is it possible to add a id to increase uniqueness?. eg. user_id = 1001, convert to 7 characters (0001001) then use the result to generate 6 characters unique

Comment: @PaStay: I don't see how using an id can affect uniqueness in any way. Could you elaborate on your idea?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: This is my ideal:
a-z corresponds to 0-25. I have user_id = 2345678 (maximum 9_999_999):
2345678/26 = 90218, remainder 10(k), 90218/26 = 3469, remainder 24(y), 3469/26 = 133, remainder 11(l), 133/10 = 13, remainder 3(3)...So with id 2345678 we have a new code kyl331

Comment: But it doesn't seem possible

Comment: "133/10 = 13, remainder 3(3)" - shouldn't it be "c"? Anyhow, there's not one random bit in this transformation. It's just writing your id in base26.

Comment: If you generate random 6 character ids, where each character is a lower-case ASCII letter (a-z), there are only 308915776 unique ids (26 ^ 6). And you'll start seeing duplicates long before you generate all the ids.